# Overlapping in statistical multiplexing

Tags: routing

I am reading about statistical multiplexing in packet switching and I don't understand one thing. What happens if two packets arrive at router at the same time? Is it possible? If not, why? If yes, how the router knows which bit belongs to which packet?

Comment: Do you mean two packets arriving on the same router interface at the same time? That doesn't happen because data arrive one bit at a time.

Comment: Yeah, but single packet consists of more bits. So I mean a situation where bits of two different packets interleave on the same router enterence(when the router is parsing incoming packet).

Comment: That is not what happens. If a channel is occupied while a host is sending, then another host cannot use the channel until the first host is done. Search for things like CSMA/CD (ethernet) and CSMA/CA (Wi-Fi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are not understanding how different layer-1/2 technologies work. While it may be possible, from a purely layer-1 point of view, to interleave bits on the wire, there are checks in place to prevent that from happening. For instance, ethernet uses CSMA/CD so that only one host can transmit a frame at any given time. If two hosts transmit simultaneously, then there is a collision, and the collision is detected, the transmissions stop, and everything is discarded.

Entire packets may be multiplexed because packets have labels, such as source and destination addresses, but bits are much more difficult to multiplex because they have no labels. Some protocols, e.g. TDMA, do this by setting aside particular time periods for bits from a particular source, but that does waste bandwidth if the sources with other time periods do not send anything; a source cannot use the time periods for other devices. It boils down to setting things up so that only one device can transmit on a channel at any one time.